# Hydrogen bonding and dichotomous Markov process

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, stochastic-processes

The hydrogen bonding function between water and monomer (from a micelle/bilayer) can be defined as $h(t) = 1$ if the **hydrogen bond exists** between the two and $h(t) = 0$, if there is **no hydrogen bonding**, at any time t.

This seems to be like dichotomous Markov process. But a question that remains to be answered is, if this process is stationary (which it is, in the case of dichotomous Markov process) ?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? You're modelling a bond's existence as a boolean property; what are the conditions for changing between the states? I think your answer will depend on that.

Comment: The answer seems to me to be yes, because bond formation and breaking is a Poisson process.

Comment: .. is it? If I'm tracking a single water molecule, and it had a bond a moment ago and suddenly it doesn't, it seems likely that it's closeby and could reform a bond. But if there has been a bond absent for a while, then the water molecule has probably drifted away, and I will less expect a bond to form soon.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg I don't mean from the point of view of a particular water molecule, but rather from a particular site (e.g. the hydrophilic group of a surfactant) where *any* water molecule could, in principle, bind. Also, both the forming and breaking of bonds involves overcoming free energy barriers, and such events are (at least approximately) Poisson.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg : The bond conditions are imposed geometrically (with a cut-off distance and bond angle). I am defining this boolean function to use it in my simulation results on self-assembly and then calculate its autocorrelation functions !!!